# _POST not grabbing data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a login system and I am having issues with a post forum. Here is what I have I feel like I have tried almost everything with no luck.

I have tried renaming the names, and echo out info. The username works just fine it is the hiddenPass I am having trouble with.

```
    <script>
        function changeFormLogin() {
            var pass = document.getElementById('getPass').value;
            var username  = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var getSalt = <?php echo $salt ?>;
            var hashpass = sha256(getSalt+pass);

            document.getElementById("hiddenPass").value = hashpass;
            document.getElementById("hiddensalt").value = getSalt;
        }     
    </script>

    <h2>Sign Up Here</h2>
    <form onsubmit="changeFormLogin()" action="tryLogin.php" METHOD="POST">
        <p>Email</p>
        <input id="username" type="email" name="username" placeholder="Enter Email" value = "<?php echo $username ?>" required>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input id="getPass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="••••••" required>
        <!-- Add two hidden fields right here -->
        <input id="hiddenPass" type="hidden" name="hiddenPass1" value="">
        <input id="hiddensalt" type="hidden" name="hiddensalt" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In">
    </form>
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
   <?php
   include_once('connect.php');


   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['hiddenPass1'];  
   $salt = $_POST['hiddensalt'];
   $userid = "";
   $valid = "";
```

Comment: Is hashpass a valid value at the javascript??

Comment: It's just a variable so it should be. I was able to register the user just fine.

Comment: What's the length of the column in the database? It's possible it's being truncated.

Comment: I verified that the actual user registration works this is the login page. So when I echo out the $password nothing is returned so I know that is the issue idk why though.

Comment: I mean if you do like alert(hashpass); what is displayed for you?

Comment: It will spit out the hash password. Thats how I knew it was working.

Comment: Do you have a race condition here?  Does it submit before or after the function changes the values?  Try setting a default value for `hiddenPass1` and see if it sends the default.  (After researching this a bit, this might be just a shot in the dark... but simple to try)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing send the form in the `changeFormLogin` function in order to submit the form, don't forget add id to your form

```
document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit();
```